# Jupyter notebook : kernel died msg when loading big CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, turi-create

I am using a `Jupiter Notebook` for making a `machine learning model` using `turicreate`. When ever I upload a big `.csv` file, I get a message: `kernel died`. Since I am new in python is there an other way to Batch loading file or anyone nows how to fix this issue ?

The csv file is 52.9 MB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

53MB is not a big file ! You should try to load this in a ipython terminal to test.

Load as you would in a Jupyter to see if you have any issue. If there is no issue, This could be a bad installation of Jupyter.

**Note** : The kernel dies mostly when you're out of RAM. But 53MB is not that big, assuming you have at least 2 or 4G or RAM on your laptop, an error like this shouldn't happend

Comment: Hi @Alexandre Sullet. I read about that, but I use a 2018 16GB MacBook Pro so I guess is not a RAM issue.

Comment: Did you try to load it into a _ipython_ terminal ?

Comment: No, I am completely new in Python and I am not sure how to do all those steps. But I will try soon or later since I am facing the same issue with the same son file also.

Comment: Open your terminal, type "ipython". The python interpreter will load.
Just load your csv as it was a jupyter notebook, e.g :
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(YOUR_DATA, sep = YOUR_SEP) and see if there if any issue.
You can also replace the last line by pd.read_csv(YOUR_DATA, sep = YOUR_SEP, nrows = 10) to see if it load correctly on the first 10 lines. If not, your file might be corrupted

Comment: Hi Alexander I posted a more detailed question since the above is not so detailed. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702855/the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-always-when-i-am-loading-a-large-file